# Magento is not installing in localhost(windows): SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists:

Tags: magento-1.8, error, windows

I was a regular user of magento 1 month before but now i found difficult to install the magento.
Magento is not installing in localhost neither in XAMPP nor in WAMP all the versions and keep on showing the following error:

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 142520047

I have tried all the setting options that are present on all the support forums.
Please someone help me in finding the solution.

These are the errors in report

```
a:5:{i:0;s:193:"Error in file: "C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Api2\sql\api2_setup\install-1.0.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 La table 'api2_acl_role' existe déjà";i:1;s:912:"#0 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.0.0.0')
#2 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.0.0.0')
#3 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 C:\wamp\www\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:44:"/magento/index.php/install/wizard/installDb/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Comment: goto var/report and check the error in file 142520047

Comment: at what set your getting error

Comment: copy the content of the file 142520047 which is their in the var/report

Comment: Please tell me how can i solve these errors

Comment: check if all required extensions of magento are enabled in your local setup.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL seems to complain that table or view already exists during install. I would start with wiping the database by dropping all the tables.

Comment: i also tried this but still there is no effect anyway thanks for the information you shared

Comment: Alright .. the next thing I would check is to make sure that the user has all the necessary permissions to drop and/or alter tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the file which you got in the error message, like here go to the path

```
C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Api2\sql\api2_setup\install-1.0.0.0.php
```

and try rename the `install-1.0.0.0.php` to `~install-1.0.0.0.php` and save it and then try installing again.

there will be many file which comes in the process change all the files name like this.

I got the same issue once and I did the same thing. and all work fine for me.

Comment: it worked fine, because you deactivated all the install/update scripts and had a lot of luck, to not use a single feature of them.
Working but very very bad advice

Comment: the solution is not working either

Comment: Well may be I am lucky in past, but thanks for giving me the advice and cleared the problems which will arise by this.
Thanks Flyingmana

Comment: AnshulVyas as you have seen its not the proper solution, but are you installing the fresh magento or some backup.

Comment: i am installing fresh magento and all the versions that i can find

Comment: Ok and what about database, are you creating the fresh db or creating the db with magento's sample data.

Comment: i am creating a new db

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this table?

```
api2_acl_role
```

Update the rows in that table as per conditions and requirements, clear cache by going to var/cache.

Comment: Are you installing fresh magento or installing magento by using backup DB?

Comment: Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.0.0.0')?? Locate this in your DB, update the version.

Answer (score 0):

I got to answer now. I had the same issue and solved it these way:

- Go to xampp and than click config in Apache row.
- Open PHP (`php.ini`) file.
- Ctrl+F if using english keyboard and find `max_execution_time` and set it to 3.600 or 0 (0 means infinite)
- Again Ctrl+F if using english keyboard and find `max_input_time` and set it equal to 3.600 or 0.
- Now retry and just wait. It will work.

This happens because Magento need more time to execute all the tables in mysql and **by default the max time execution is 30 or 60.**